# Why does the representation theory of $S_n$ fit perfectly with young tableaux?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

This is a "soft question" of sorts. I've been studying the representation theory of the symmetric group, and I continue to be bewildered.

> Why does the representation theory of $S_n$ relate to partitions and young tableaux?

It seems completely unmotivated to me that all of this works.

1. Partitions feels like a "number theoretic" object to me, and second only a combinatorial one.
2. The conditions imposed for a partition to be a tableaux (rows weakly increasing, columns strictly increasing) feel arbitrary.
3. The actual point of contact, that of `conjugacy class ~ cycle type ~ partition` feels reasonable. The part with `permutation ~ pair of yonng tableaux` (via the [Robinson Schensted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson%E2%80%93Schensted_correspondence) correspondence) feels unbelievable.
4. The formula:

$$
\sum_{\lambda \in \texttt{partitions}(n)} (\dim\lambda)^2 = n!
$$

is one such amazing "coincidence" that works from both the bijection point of view (Robinson Schensted) and the [representation theoretic point of view](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_of_degrees_of_irreducible_representations_equals_order_of_group).

Is there some sort of "deep reason" of why it all works out so well? I'd love to understand, because I am currently simply mystified.

Comment: Isn’t asking why it fits with Young Tableaux a little like asking why hole in the ground first so neatly with the water in it? The Tableaux were constructed to match the representation theory...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I wasn't aware of that! Is there some place I can learn the historical perspective of why they were defined the way they are? The current source I am following (bijective combinatorics) provides roughly no motivation

Comment: The tableaux arising in $S_n$ representations are standard (strictly increasing both along columns and rows). The semi-standard (weakly increasing along rows, strictly down columns) come up in representations of $GL_n$, or in the symmetric function algebra with Schur functions.

Comment: One interesting way to start with the easy fact of “irreps of $S_n$ are indexed by Young diagrams” and end up at the definition of standard tableaux, is the Okounkov-Vershik approach to the representation theory. Roughly, you can figure out (without tableaux) that the restriction of an irrep to $S_{n-1}$ is multiplicity-free, and hence decomposes an $S_{n}$-irrep into a direct sum of $S_{n-1}$-irreps, each indexed by a young diagram with $n-1$ boxes. After some work, the diagrams that appear are all given by removing a box from the original diagram (such that the result is again Young).

Comment: @Joppy I'd gladly accept your comment as an answer if you're willing to post it :) If you could expand on this approach to representation theory, perhaps with a reference or two, it would be super!

Comment: Repeating this process over and over means that an $S_n$-irrep indexed by a partition $\lambda$ decomposes into a direct sum of one-dimensional spaces, each indexed by a chain of Young diagrams, starting with the diagram with one box, adding one box each time, and ending at $\lambda$. These chains bijectively correspond to standard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$. So, this is one way that we might come up with the definition of a standard Young tableaux if we had only known about partitions / Young diagrams to begin with.

Comment: You can look up the paper by Okounkov and Vershik if you like, and Chapter 2 of “Linear and Projective Representations of Symmetric Groups” by Alexander Kleshchev develops the theory in this way too. I’m not sure I want to post this as an answer though, in case somebody else has interesting observations to share :)